# File Size in File.length different from Windows explorer

Tags: java, windows, file

I'm using `File(outputFilePath).length()` to get the size of a file.  But Windows Explorer tells me it's slightly larger, i.e. 144835 vs. 151,412 bytes.  Is this surprising or expected?

Comment: Size or size on disk?

Comment: Sotirios, Size.  Size on disk is 151,552 bytes.

Comment: So the OS allocates 151552 bytes on disk to store the file but only actually needs 144835.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is because windows can handle disk in blocks that is usually 4Kb that is 4096bytes. This is the smallest part of disk space that the OS can handle separately. So when a file does not fill an entire block, disk space gets wasted, and even though the actual file size is smaller, it still occupies the disk space of the allocated block(s) - in your case it uses up 37 4Kb blocks. You can change block size but you have to format your disk to do that. The Java `File.length()` returns the actual size in bytes.